# autoredeploy new image to a docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want docker to automatically redeploy my stack to a swarm when an image update is pushed. Before swarm, this was possible as documented here https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/auto-redeploy/ . Is this feature available in swarm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this feature should be introduced in swarm sometimes in q2 2017 https://forums.docker.com/t/what-is-the-point-of-the-new-beta-swarm-mode/29180

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, still answering with hope this will be of some use to who comes looking here.

Check this one out, uses Docker hub webhook to redeploy services based on the image name & tag.

https://hub.docker.com/r/riyasdeen/docker-swarm-redeploy/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes